# Adding a column in Sqlite3 of Grafana

Tags: orm, sqlite, grafana

## Background

In order to prevent Grafana alerts during weekends and holidays, I want to add a `workdays_only` column to the `alert` table.

I've added it in `alert_mig.go` and rebuilt.

## Problem

When trying to save to this column, I get:

```
EROR[01-29|16:28:23] Failed to save alerts                    logger=context userId=1 orgId=1 uname=admin error="no such column: workdays_only"
```

## Question

How can I apply the new migration on the database?

Comment: Please attach the code for creating the column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this to the migration file (in this case the `alert_mig.go` under `addAlertMigrations`):

```
mg.AddMigration("Add column workdays_only", NewAddColumnMigration(alertV1, &Column{
    Name: "workdays_only", Type: DB_Bool, Nullable: false, Default: "0",
}))
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.